# d3.js rotate 27deg radar

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creating a radar chart and trying to rotate it by 27 degrees, but my images I have defined on my axis rotate too. This is not what I want, I want the images to stay at its place.

```
.radarChart{
        /* Rotate chart */
        -ms-transform: rotate(27deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(27deg);
        transform: rotate(27deg);
        }
```

The problem is that I cannot rotate the image back with -27degrees as I expected. I have an example running here: http://leanza.nl/teamradar/

As you can see the radar chart did turn, but the images with numbers 1 to 8 rotate too. And the legend rotated too, this is also not wanted.

Can anyone give me a hint how to turn the images 1.png to 8.png normal and the legend too?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is turned because the css rules are applied to all the child elements of the div with radarChart class. Add more specific class names to all the elements that you want to turn and thne use this more specific class name in your css code. You can add class names to objects easily while generating new elements in d3 as follows:

```
.attr("class", "more_specific_class_name")
```

or

```
.classed("more_specific_class_name", true)
```